# In Recyclerview projects Mainactivity create object of url, Adapter parse load Url in default browser. Try to in WebView?

Tags: java, android-webview, android-recyclerview

there is Images, Names and URL object in MainActivity code which is view in recycler item:

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        images = new int[]{R.drawable.google, R.drawable.facebook,
                R.drawable.gaana, R.drawable.youtube, R.drawable.oracle,
                R.drawable.wikipedia};

        webNames = new String[]{"Google", "Gacebook", "Gaana",
                "YouTube", "Oracle", "Wikipedia"};

        webUrl = new String[]{"https://www.google.com.",
                "https://www.facebook.com",
                "https://www.gaana.com",
                "https://www.youtube.com",
                "https://www.oracle.com",
                "https://www.wikipedia.org"};
```

Adapter which hold Image, Name and Url which parse to recyclerview items and  by onClicklistener it load in default browser:

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.webName.setText(webNames[position]);
        holder.wIcon.setImageResource(images[position]);

        holder.wIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                  Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebPage.class);
                  intent.putExtra("webUrl", webUrl.toString());
//                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
//                intent.setData(Uri.parse(placeGuide[holder.getAdapterPosition()]));
                  context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
}
```

try to load url in webview:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_page);
        WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.weView);

        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        webView.loadUrl(bundle.getString("webUrl"));
    }
```

i want to load Url in Webview

Comment: plzz ans. any one

Answer (score 0):

**RecycleView**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebPage.class);
intent.putExtra("webUrl", webUrl[position]);
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**Another Activity**

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
String url=intent.getStringExtra("webUrl");
webView.loadUrl(url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace `webUrl.toString()` in **RecyclerViewAdapter** to `webUrl[position]`, everything will be ok.